# can not get the params data by using props.route in react navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Below is the javascript code:

```
 const onSelectEdit = (id) => {
            `    `props.navigation.navigate("EditProduct", {
                  productId: id,
                  });
             };



const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={userProducts}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={(itemData) => (
        <ProductItem
          image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
          title={itemData.item.title}
          price={itemData.item.price}
          onSelect={() => {
            onSelectEdit("p1");
          }}>
          <Button
            color={Colors.primary}
            title="Edit"
            onPress={() => {
              onSelectEdit("p1");
            }}
          />
```

From this page I want t pass productId through navigation.navigate. and want catch that parameter from another screen,

```
const EditProduct = (props) => {
  const prodId = props.route.params.productId;
```

But this error occured - undefined is not an object( evaluating 'props.route.params.productId')

what should I do to fix this

TIA

Comment: Are you using a nested navigator ?

Comment: yes. nested navigator